# Handling buttons in custom dialogs

Tags: android

I have a little problem with an android custom dialog.

I construct a custom dialog in the onCreateDialog(int) function:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
```

I have a onClick(View) function in the same class:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.dialog_button:
            Log.i("pma57","dialog button pressed");
            break;
        case R.id.main_button:
            showDialog(DIALOG_CUSTOM);
            break;
        }       
    }
```

This is the XML definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="20dp"
  android:paddingRight="20dp"
  android:paddingBottom="20dp">
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enter_username" />
      <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Dialog shows up. But the Button does not work (the app crashs)- which is quite ok because the onClick-function for the callback is defined in my main activity - and the dialog is a new activity (am I right?).

But I realy don't know how i implement a button in the dialog - I think this is a fundamental understanding problem of the technic. The long way would be to subclass Dialog and write everything there - but is there another way which I don't see?

Comment: I do not see main_button in your xml file. That might be the problem you are having.

Comment: thats because its just the important part of the program - the main button is in the other xml file for the main activity.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way round it that I use, rather than having a switch block is to use onClickListeners for the buttons:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    // Perform button logic
}
```

Note that you are finding the view from the dialog, not just calling straight to findViewById as that would return a null pointer as there would be not dialog_button on the application view.

Comment: ahhh. I tried it that way but i missed the dialog before dialog.findViewById() that could be the right solution for me! thank you!

Comment: Yep, I tried it - with dialog.findViewById() I was able to set the listener to my main activity - works like a charme now. THANK YOU again!

Comment: No problem - easiest way to remember it, when you are working in your activity it will have a view - if you call findViewById you are getting a reference to the ID of the object (button) in the view - the context here is your activity - if you create a second view - in this case the dialog (could be named anything obviously) you want to dialog.findViewById as this will change from looking at the contexts view for the reference to the dialog view for the reference.