# dialogs problem

Tags: android, dialog

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("PubQuiz");


            TextView player = new TextView(this);
            player.setText("Player1");
            builder.setView(player);

            TextView team = new TextView(this);
            team.setText("TeamA");
            builder.setView(team);


        return builder.create();

       }
```

how do I get the second textview to show?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom dialog for that. Take a look here: [Handling buttons in custom dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113939/handling-buttons-in-custom-dialogs)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("PubQuiz");

    LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(context);
    lay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView player = new TextView(this);
    player.setText("Player1");
    lay.addView(player);

    TextView team = new TextView(this);
    team.setText("TeamA");
    lay.addView(team);

    builder.setView(lay);

    return builder.create();
}
```

**Try this**

Comment: thanks :) what does context mean on this line LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(context);

Comment: You can write Activityname.this

Comment: If i added like this              Button twopoints = new Button(this);
             twopoints.setText(" 2 points");
             lay.addView(twopoints); do i add the actionlistener on that block of code

Comment: You can add actionListener on that Button