# Get reference to widgets and set its event handlers on AlertDialog created using custom XML layout

Tags: android, events, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have created AlertDialog, which has some buttons and a gridview, from layout using `LayoutInflater`, and have overridden `onCreateDialog()` in my Activity class, where it packs in the layout and returns `Dialog` object.

And in `onCreate()` method of the activity class, I show the dialog using `showDialog(id)` where id is the constant that is associated with a particular dialog.

Now, I want to bind click events to the widgets I have on the AlertDialog which is just shown. I do it as follows:

```
showDialog(DLG_INPUT_FORM);
inputform = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
inputform.setContentView(R.layout.input_form);

edtName = (EditView) inputform.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
btnCheck = (Button) inputform.findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
txtStatus = (TextView) inputform.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

//This event is never triggered.
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String name = edtName.getText().toString();
        //Do Something with the "name"
        txtStatus.setText("Available");
    }
});
```

This doesn't throw any exception, but clicking on buttons doesn't do anything, in fact event is not triggered at all.

What is wrong in the code?

**UPDATE:**

The issue is kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113939/handling-buttons-in-custom-dialogs/), I'm also getting reference to widgets on Dialog for `btnCheck` and `txtStatus` but something is wrong with click event that it doesn't work.

Comment: try changing this to yourclassname.this in the second line of the code

Comment: or else instead of showDialog(ID) popup the dialog in the onCreate method itself

Comment: But I need to launch dialog based on certain event, is it fine to call `onCreatDialog(id)`, instead of `showDialog()`, and use the returning object?

Comment: handle the event if possible in your oncreate method and depending on the condition display the dialog without using onCreateDialog and showDialog() as they r not working. post what have you written inside ur onCreate dialog method and show dialog method.

Comment: I tried binding the events within `onCreateDialog()` but that thrown RuntimeException while attempting to open dialog, hence I tried to do that in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Kush you create separate activity for handling the grid view functionlity and it events etc... But for making it like dialog just apply dialog theme in manifest for that activity.. Its so simple and you can handle the events very easily.

Comment: @Dinash: Having a dedicated activity for the dialog is not feasible here, I need to workout in the dialog. Or else, is it possible to have a normal activity running and showing in the background, while Dialog's own Activity is launched?

Comment: @Kush can you please let me know for what purpose you need the dialog, so that i can think on it and let you know if any other alternative can be done.

Comment: @Dinash: The dialog had 9 buttons, and the app I'm developing is a card based game, where dialog plays an important role. As of now, I've followed your suggestion to create an activity and have it look as dialog (through manifest setting), and works fine, but still I don't get why event was not getting triggered in the first approach of mine, so the question is still open for answers.