# How To Control Click Event Of Dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog

I Want to Control Click Event of Dialog in This There Are Three Items

when I click On Milk ..Other Function Perform..when I click On Butter other Function Perform
i want to know how to control Item Selection

here Is My Code of Dialog Box

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserModel user = (UserModel)getActivity(). getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
        String User_id= contactList.get(position).get("User_Id");
        String Request_id=contactList.get(position).get("Request_Id");
        String Accpeter_Id=String.valueOf(user.getUser_Id());
         //List items
        final CharSequence[]items = {"Milk", "Butter", "Cheese"};
        //Prepare the list dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //Set its title
        builder.setTitle("Request Confirmation");
        //Set the list items and assign with the click listener
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // Click listener
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(items.equals(items[item])){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi friends CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(items.equals(items[item])){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi butter Mutter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cheesy way hehehe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        //display dialog box
        alert.show();
    }
```

when I click On Any Item else Block Is printing on Any Click

i set Condition Like This

```
if(items.equals(items[item])){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi friends CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else if(items.equals(items[item])){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi butter Mutter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else{  

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cheesy way hehehe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

only Else Condition Displaying For Any Item Click
Telll Me What I m doing Wrong and whare ...

thanku

Comment: I found a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113939/handling-buttons-in-custom-dialogs/4114017#4114017

It works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this **item** is the position of click:

```
switch(item){
   case 0:// first item in your list
   break; 
   case 1:// second item in your list
   break; 
   case 2:// third item in your list
   break; 

}
```

The problem I see in your code is that you are checking if array equels to string.

Comment: Thanx It Work And The Way u  Suggested I like ..Thnx For Helping Me

Answer (score 1):

Your equal statement is wrong you are checking your `CharSequence[] items` with an item of it's Charsequence[].

```
if(items.equals(items[item]))
{
}
```

try this :

```
if(items[0].equals[items[item]])
{
}
else if (items[1].equals[items[item]])
.
.
.
```

Comment: ..let me Try If It Work I will Accept Ur Ans

Comment: Giving Error Change Items To Int..not Working

Comment: @ᏕᏗᎷᎷᎩᏇᏗᏕᏋᏋᎷ : can you add what you wrote?it should n't give such error.

Comment: @ᏕᏗᎷᎷᎩᏇᏗᏕᏋᏋᎷ : try items[item].toString() instead.