# Custom dialog with buttons leading to webpage

Tags: android

I am trying to create a pop up dialog which will open when you click an item from a navigation drawer. I would like to put buttons in it which will lead to webpages. Since I am quite new to Android, I have no idea how to implement this. To show you visually, I would like it to look something like this:

[Pop up Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGaVN.png)

Regards

Comment: Have you searched for this? There are so many examples and codes you can find in SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling buttons in custom dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113939/handling-buttons-in-custom-dialogs)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find an example where a custom dialog is open when the user clicks on item from the navigation drawer. If you happen to know any examples, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) providing your custom layout, like this:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false); 
        // R.layout.fragment_dialog is a .xml layout YOU provide and it is located into the /layout folder of the project!

        // Provide the behavior for the dialog here, say react to click on the buttons and so on...

        return v;
    }   
}
```

In the activity which is hosting the dialog you provide a method to show it:

```
void showDialog() {

    mStackLevel++;

    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog"); // Checking if there's already a dialog with the tag "dialog"
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog"); // Setting a tag "dialog" for the newly created dialog
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I still don't get it. Where do I declare the tag "dialog"? Also, can I implement a method showDialog() in my hosting activity, and call that method inside "public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)" (which is in the same activity)?

Comment: You don't declare any string, you use the string "dialog" straightforward.

Comment: For the other question: yes, I think you can do that. Please try it in your code before posting other questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("you");
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.custom_layout);


            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.findViewById(your button id).setOnClickListerner(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            });
            alertDialog.show();
```

if you dont want to set **OK** and **Cancel** buttons just remove that code , i hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your **[custom Dialog](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)**

. Just inflate your `xml` view to `Dialog`

```
public void customDialogBox(Context mContext){
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
        text.setText("Custom dialog Android example.");

        dialog.show();

        Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
        // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Close dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
```